# How to make call from Emulator using DDMS

Tags: android

I find many things in DDMS Emulator Control tab, I just want to make/simulate a call from DDMS. How to do that. Also where can I find details about Emulator Control tab?
Thanx

Comment: When I do this, it at first seems like it doesn't work.  LogCat spits out a lot of errors.  But then when it ceases attempting to call, the emulator instance of the device says 1 missed call, with the phone number I used.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Call as if to simulate a phone call?

1 Window > Open Perspective > DDMS

2 'Emulator Control' Tab

3 In Telephony Actions, enter any number in 'Incoming Number' textfield.

4 Choose 'Voice' from the two radiobuttons.

5 Finally, click on `Call`.

To disconnect, click `Hang up`.

More [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html#using-ddms).

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

I think you have received an appropriate answer for making a call to your emulator. Just refer more details about Emulator Control tab at link: 
 http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html#ops-location

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Using DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html) where you will find all the required info.

Answer (score 0):

You can do DDMS jobs via telnet:

Type in CMD:

1. telnet
2. open localhost 5554
3. sms send 000000 hello

The list of available commands:

```
   event            simulate hardware events
   geo              Geo-location commands
   gsm              GSM related commands
   cdma             CDMA related commands
   kill             kill the emulator instance
   network          manage network settings
   power            power related commands
   quit|exit        quit control session
   redir            manage port redirections
   sms              SMS related commands
   avd              control virtual device execution
   window           manage emulator window
   qemu             QEMU-specific commands
   sensor           manage emulator sensors
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than DDMS, there is one more option:

The emulator automatically forwards simulated voice calls from one instance to another. To send a voice call, use the dialer application application, respectively, from one of the emulators.

To initiate a simulated voice call to another emulator instance:

```
1.Launch the dialer application on the originating emulator instance.
2.As the number to dial, enter the console port number of the instance you'd like to call. You can determine the console port number of the target instance by checking its window title, where the console port number is reported as "Android Emulator (<port>).
3.Press "Dial". A new inbound call appears in the target emulator instance.
```